# React-Admin: <ReferenceManyField> is not fetching relevant results

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have three tables (shown below):

**Stories table:**

[image]

**Questions table:**

Here, fetching "questions" using the `story_id` works fine.

[image]

**Questions-choices table:**
**(The problem)**
When we fetch "question-choices" based on `question_id`, it doesn't return relevant results but rather returns all "question_choices". Interestingly, if I use the `correct_answer` column instead of `question_id` it works fine (fetches specific results).

[image]

Below is the `react-admin` code:

```js
// To fetch "questions" based on `story_id`
<ReferenceManyField
  addLabel={false}
  reference="questions"
  target="story_id"
  sort={{ field: 'created_at', order: 'DESC' }}
>
  <Datagrid>
    <TextField source="text" />
    <DateField source="created_at" />
    <ShowButton />
  </Datagrid>
</ReferenceManyField>


// And to fetch "question_choices" based on `question_id`
<ReferenceManyField
  addLabel={false} 
  target="question_id" // if use "correct_answer" instead of "question_id", it works
  reference="questionchoices"
>
  <Datagrid hasBulkActions>
    <TextField label="Name" source="name" />
    <TextField label="correct answer" source="correct_answer" />
    <DateField source="created_at" />
    <ShowButton />
    <EditButton/>
  </Datagrid>
</ReferenceManyField>
```

How can I handle this problem?

Comment: Sounds strange because ideally your code should work. Am interested to see the actual errors. Kindly share some `errors` generated when you use `target=question_id`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was issue in the server-side, the server was not responding against foreign key ID